MudBlazor MudNumercField with thousand separator
Can I set Format parameter somehow to display the number with thousand separatot in MudNumericField, please. I tried to set it to "n" but it didn't work.
For example: 151 342

Unclear, what is your expected input and expected output?

Hi RBee! Input is a number e.g. 151342 (int) and output is a text 151 342 (string). :)

You can add C# custom numeric format strings to MudNumericField.Format property.
e.g.
For your input of 151342 and expected output of 151 342
You can use "### ###" or "000 000"

"0" Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.


"#" Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

<MudNumericField Format="### ###" T="int" @bind-Value="_myValue"/>
<MudNumericField Format="000 000" T="int" @bind-Value="_myValue"/>

@code {
    public int _myValue = 151342;
}

 MudBlazor Snippet
